# En clases como puedo meter un diccionario en una lista?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Buenas mi duda es seguramente muy basica pero no soy capaz de resolverla.
Consiste basicamente en como puedo añadir mi diccionario tortuga a la lista tortugas. Lo he intentado con append pero me dice que tortugas no está definida, alguna sugerencia?
El ejemplo es el siguiente:

```
class Galapago:
    tortugas=[]

    def __init__(self):

        self.x= 0
        self.sprite= "lo"
        self.color= "bue"
        tortuga={}
        tortuga['sprite']= self.sprite
        tortuga['x']=self.x
        tortuga['color']= self.color
        tortugas.append(tortuga)
    alex=Galapago()
```

Busco crear esa lista (tortugas) para poder luego utilizar sus datos en otras funciones, como por ejemplo la siguiente:

```
    def set_pencolor(self,color):
        for n in range (len(tortugas)):
            if tortugas[n]['sprite']== sprite:
                for m in tortugas[n]:
                    tortugas[n]['color']= color
```

Answer (score 2):

Los diccionarios en Python, como casi todos los tipos iterables, se pueden convertir fácilmente en iterables de otro tipo. En este caso valdría con `nuevalista = list(tortugas)`

Por ejemplo si tenemos este diccionario:

```
tortugas = {"sprite": "tortuga1", "x": 7, "color": "verde", "Enferma": False}
```

Se puede pasar a una lista las claves del diccionario así:

```
>>> tortugas_k = list(tortugas)
>>> tortugas_k
['sprite', 'x', 'color', 'Enferma']
```

Si lo que se desea es pasar los valores del diccionario a una lista:

```
>>> tortugas_v = list(tortugas.values())
>>> tortugas_v
['tortuga1', 7, 'verde', False]
```

Y ya por último, si lo que desea es conservar tanto las claves como los valores, éstos se pueden encapsular en una tupla y después añadirlos a una lista:

```
>>> tortugas2 = [(k, v) for k, v in tortugas.items()]
>>> tortugas2
[('sprite', 'tortuga1'), ('x', 7), ('color', 'verde'), ('Enferma', False)]
```

El hecho de que se encuentre dentro de una clase es irrelevante

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
class Galapago:
    #variables de clase
    x= 0
    sprite= "lo"
    color= "bue"
    tortugas=[]

    def __init__(self):

        tortuga={}
        tortuga['sprite']= self.sprite
        tortuga['x']=self.x
        tortuga['color']= self.color
        self.tortugas.append(tortuga)

    # para obtener la lista
    def get_tortugas(self):
        return self.tortugas


g = Galapago();
print(g.get_tortugas())
```

Comment: Efectivamente de esta manera consigo tener la lista tortugas con el diccionario que deseo. Pero a la hora de utilizar esa lista en otras funciones (ya que tortugas es una lista global) me da como error que la lista tortugas no esta definida. Como puedo lograr que funcione?

Comment: @airun Aunque respondí, creo que no respondí a tu pregunta. Para que tu código funcione debes declarar `tortugas` antes de la clase o dentro de `__init__`. Tu código no funciona porque al instanciar una clase lo 1º que se ejecuta es `__init__` y por lo tanto en ese momento no está definida. (Disculpa por haberme precipitado con la respuesta)

Comment: No te preocupes, muchas gracias por tu respuesta